# How to convert raster file into a series of SQL commands

Tags: python, raster, gdal, postgresql

I am trying to save raster data to the PostgreSQL database. I know that there exists `raster2psql.exe`, but this command limits me from adding additional columns to the table. For this reason, I would like to store the raster data after some processing directly to the DB. After analyzing the `raster2psql.exe` I figured out that the command converts a raster file into a series of SQL commands and the conversion looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO "public"."raster" ("rast","filename") VALUES ('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'::raster,'test.vrt');
```

Further, as I understood raster data is the same as data in the VALUES section. So my main question is how to convert raster data to the data type(I think it is a HEX) as shown in the VALUES section? then I will generate an SQL query to dump to directly to the database.

I have tried:

```
command = "raster2pgsql.exe -s 4326 -I -R -N -999 -a {} public.{}".format(filename, table_name)
    with Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=None, shell=True) as process:
        output = process.communicate()[0].decode("utf-8")
    # string after VALUES text
    value = re.findall(r'VALUES (.+?);',output)
```

but it gives me an error related to certificate configuration (I am using /vsicurl/). In addition, i do not want to use external commands if it can be done with GDAL/rasterio.

Is there any way of doing it with GDAL or rasterio?

Comment: Perhaps this old Python script could be useful https://github.com/greenplum-db/postgis/blob/master/raster/scripts/python/raster2pgsql.py.

Comment: @user30184 thanks a lot. that helped a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions from https://github.com/greenplum-db/postgis/blob/master/raster/scripts/python/raster2pgsql.py script helped to construct own module.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).